# Get text field value before saving node

Tags: 7, hooks

I have a a custom module in which I am implementing hook_node_presave() for a content type "ABC".

I want to get the value of a text field say 'field_test' before saving the node.

How to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code,

```
$value = $node->field_test[$node->language][0]['value']
```

This to get the value for the text field alone for other fields format will chage.

Comment: How to get the values for a node reference field

Comment: Asking a Question in comments are not accepted in the Stack Exchange ! Please create a new Question with details if needed.

Comment: @Anil Sagar: hmm ok. anyways got the answer for the question. No need to create a new question.